# Is it possible to change research focus entirely for a Post doc (for example, going from studying Biochemistry to neuroscience)?

Tags: postdocs, changing-fields

I happen to be in a lab that quantifies the kinetics of movement of molecular motors like kinesins and dyneins. However, through my literature search, I have seen some pretty fascinating research on these same proteins in the neuroscience field, though culturing neurons is something I've not done (although I've cultured mammalian cells). My question is, would it even be possible to switch to this field for my post-doc?